ListView borders depending on "scroll state"
I would like to create a scrollable list that has borders at the top and at the button but only when the list's content "overflows" in the corresponding direction. So:

when the list fits entirely into the available space: no borders.
when the list doesn't fit and

overflows at the bottom: a bottom border is shown.
overflows at the top: a bottom border is shown.
overflows at the top and the bottom: both a top and a bottom border are shown.



I tried something like that:
void initState() {
  scrollController.addListener(
    setState(() {
      checkForOverflow();
    });
  );
}

void checkForOverflow() {
  showTop = scrollController.offset > 0;
  showBottom = scrollController.position.minScrollExtent !=  scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
}

Widget build() {
  if (_scrollViewController.hasClients) {
    checkForOverflow();
  }

  return Stack(
    children: [
      ListView(controller: scrollController, builder: (){
        // build children
      }),
      if(showTop) buildTop(),
      if(showBottom) buildBottom(),
    ]
  );
}

This works as soon as I start scrolling or when the available space changes (e.g. when resizing the window). But I can't figure out how to achieve the effect when the widget builds for the first time.
